# Correct way to separate Boost test suites in different files using CLion

Tags: c++, testing, boost, cmake, clion

I'm trying to use Boost tests in my project in CLion, but I'm having some problems in making tests modular. In Boost documentation there is always only one file with all tests defined below, but as I plan to have many tests this is not good.
What I'd like to have is each test suite in a separate file and a "main" test file to execute all tests inside CLion test environment.

I found a way to do that but it is quite ugly and feels wrong so I'm looking for the right way to do this.

I am currently using this:

```
// CMakeLists.txt

...

add_executable(all_tests tests/all_tests.cpp ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(all_tests my_lib)
```

```
// tests/all_tests.cpp

#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Project Tests
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

#include "Test1.cpp"
#include "Test2.cpp"
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you mean is you want one translation unit ("cpp file") to define the test runner.

See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/adv_scenarios/entry_point_overview.html

At the bottom it shows links to 3 different organizations of your code to get one TU with the entry point.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I got it working using the shared library variant defining both entry point and initialization function, as described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/adv_scenarios/shared_lib_customizations/init_func.html). For some reason entry point alone was not enough.